# How to register simple things entity Audit extension in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, audit

I am trying to use simple things entity audit bundle in my application, but couldnt figure out the way to get this right. Please find the steps i am trying below,

1) Installed simple things bundle into vendor directory via composer file
2) Not sure where to autoload as given in the read me file 
3) Added the setting of audited entities in config.yml

```
simple_things_entity_audit:
    audited_entities:
        - AcmeDemoBundle\Entity\Vendor
        - AcmeDemoBundle\Entity\Employee
```

But Not sure how to register them as extension in doctrine configuration. I am very new to this bundle. Any help here would be really  appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the Bundle in your AppKernel?

Comment: yes i did enabled in app kernel But i am not sure how to check the versions

Answer (score 0):

Use Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Vendor instead of AcmeDemoBundle\Entity\Vendor

Comment: Mark this as an answer